# sql select 2 fields almost equivalent

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Imagine a table like this one :

```
ID - NAME
1    BART
2    LISA
3    HOMER
4    MISA
5    HOMRE
```

And i want to select only the rows where 3 or more characters are equals and following. So after this select i should get :

```
ID - NAME
2    LISA
3    HOMER
4    MISA
5    HOMRE
```

How to do that with sql server 2008 ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! You will need to define more clearly what you mean. Also, have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: I tried to use the "like" statement. But i think it can't do what i need. And i don't see which statement could be useful. I don't even know if it's possible to do that in sql.

Comment: Hm Why was this question actually closed? To me it's pretty clear what was asked for. The only think which might be a bit lacking is what was tried so far... therefore the downvotes I guess, but closing, really?

Comment: I have my answer so I don't really care

Comment: @KevinRocher: For your next question you should care, though - You were lucky that I answered before it was closed, as closed questions can't be answered anymore ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test for common characters at arbitrary positions, you can use an SQL function:

```
create function dbo.CommonChars(@str1 varchar(255), @str2 varchar(255))
returns int
begin
    declare @count int
    declare @cur int
    set @cur = 1
    set @count = 0
    while @cur <= LEN(@str1)
    begin
        if charindex(substring(@str1, @cur, 1), @str2) > 0
        begin
            set @count = @count + 1
        end
        set @cur = @cur + 1
    end
    return @count
end
```

Test data:

```
create table #test (
  id int,
  name varchar(255)
);

insert into #test 
select 1, 'BART' union all
select 2, 'LISA' union all
select 3, 'HOMER' union all
select 4, 'MISA' union all
select 5, 'HOMRE'
```

Test statement:

```
select * from #test t1 where exists
    (select 1 from #test t2
        where t1.id != t2.id and
        dbo.CommonChars(t1.name, t2.name) >= 3)
```

Returns:

```
id  name
2   LISA
3   HOMER
4   MISA
5   HOMRE
```

**Note**: If one of the strings has multiple occurences of one character, the function will not work as expected (e.g. if you have the strings "MUMMY" and "MA", "MUMMY" will be returned by above query; it has 3 Ms "in common" with "MA", since the function checks separately for each M if it is contained in any of the other strings). You'd have to e.g. delete the matched characters from the second string to prevent such behavior; I'll leave that as an exercise for the interested reader.

Comment: Thanks was easier with this implementation

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean identical characters in the same position

This won't be particularly quick, but...

```
;with cteLetters AS 
(  
   SELECT  
        ID, 
        #t.name,
        Number as Position,
        SUBSTRING(#t.name,Number,1) AS [Char]      
   FROM #t
        INNER JOIN master.dbo.spt_values 
        ON Number BETWEEN 1 AND LEN(#t.name) 
        AND type='P'      
)   
    select a1.name, a2.name
    from cteLetters a1
        inner join cteLetters a2 
            on a1.id<>a2.id
            and a1.position = a2.position -- omit this line if order doesn't matter
            and a1.char = a2.char

    group by a1.name,a2.name
    having COUNT(*)>=3
```

(I'm imagining your table is called #t, with two fields (id, name))

Comment: Not exactly what I want but I think now I'll get it thanks to you the table 'cteLetters' you created is interresting. I'll try.

Comment: It's called a `common table expression` and is a way of reusing a resultset, and also doing recursive queries.

Comment: Why use `ROW_NUMBER()`? You've already got `master.dbo.spt_values.Number` as a character position.

Comment: @AndriyM Good point - the remnants of an earlier iteration :)

Comment: This will return duplicates when there are three or more identical names (like `LISA`, `MISA`, `VISA`), but I think it's a good start, +1.